# Magento 2.3.3 Error Failed address validation: %1

Tags: magento2

Using Paypal , after placing an order customer is directed to paypal , inputs the email  CC information and etc and is directed back to magento where they choose shipping and then click on place order.

I am getting this error:

Failed address validation %1

In the system log : Failed address validation, Email has a wrong format
However Email is valid with Paypal email address.

Any help would be appreciated.

The full error is:

> main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Failed address validation: Email has
> a wrong format
>
> Trace:
>
> ## 1 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submitQuote()
>
> called at [vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php:447]
>
> ## 2 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submit() called at [vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php:807]

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like Customers -> Enable Auto Group Assignment set to "No" fixed the issue. I'm still testing to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the bug reports on get such as [/issues/29473](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29473) and [issues/25399](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25399).

Both suggest that the option

**`Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group`**

is causing the issue when set to "`Yes`" in the

`Customers > Customer configuration settings section`.

Thus, setting this option to `No` will provide a workaround the checkout issue.

```
Setting "Store > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group" to "No"
```

Also:

```
PayPal Express Checkout configured with option "Skip Order Review Step" to "No"
```

Paypal setting may contribute to the issue, it did not in my case as I once changed the customer auto assignment to `No` the issue was fixed.